# Culture invariant StringFormat does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, cultureinfo

I have this weird behavior where I load data from a `DataView` to a `DataGrid`. I have a custom `DataGridBoundColumn` with a `ContentTemplateSlector`. The selector work very well, but as the columns receive directly the value as `DateTime` I do not specify a property, just `Binding`.

The `d` of `DateTime.StringFormat` does not do anything, but a `dd/MM/yyyy` works just fine. Same issue for `Double`. Even tried `{}{0:D}` but `{##0.00##}` works fine.

Any clue for the weird behavior?

```
protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
{
   Binding binding = new Binding((Binding).Path.Path(){Source= dataItem};

   ContentControl content= new ContentControl
   {
      ContentTemplateSelector = (TableDataPointConvert)cell.FindResource("TemplateSelector")
   };

   content.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
```

Selector:

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
   if(item is DateTime)
   {
      return DateTemplate;
   }
}
```

The xaml part that does not work:

```
<DataTemplat x:Key="DateTemplate">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=d}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Does work:

```
<DataTemplat x:Key="DateTemplate">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thank you,

Comment: I use this when Binding date `{Binding PropertyWithDateHere, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Same issue for Double. Even tried {}{0:D} but {##0.00##} works fine.

The `D`/`d` [format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) is only applicable to **integral types**, not `double`, use `F`/`f` instead, e.g.:

```
StringFormat=F
StringFormat={}{0:F}}
StringFormat=F0
StringFormat={}{0:F0}}
...
```

> The "d" of DateTime.StringFormat does not do anything, but a dd/MM/yyyy works just fine.

I think that you are mixing up two concepts. The `d` used in `StringFormat` like below is a standard format specifier that will format the date to use the [short date pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#the-short-date-d-format-specifier), like *6/15/2009 (en-US)*, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#ShortDate).

```
StringFormat=d
StringFormat={}{0:d}
```

On the other hand, the string format below is a [custom format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), where `d` has a different meaning stands for the day of the month.

```
StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}}
```

The confusing thing about this is that you cannot use `d` only like above and expect it to be the day of the month, because it will be [interpreted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dSpecifier) as the standard format specifier.

> If the "d" format specifier is used without other custom format specifiers, it's interpreted as the "d" standard date and time format specifier.

Comment: Sorry and thank you, I think I actually tried with G2. I very much understand the concept and I actually want to use it, but in both cases it returns a very blank cell!